# Removing the system settings option from the system Menu in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

I am looking to lockdown Ubuntu for an end user, the Ubuntu version and GNOME version is 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2.  I am looking to remove the 'System Settings' option from the system menu via configuration if possible.

[image: System Settings]

Comment: is the desktop session Ubuntu?  what is the DisplayManager gdm3 or lightdm?

Comment: To me, the screenshot does not look like Gnome Shell 3.18.

Comment: Its lightdm I just looked on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.

Comment: @vanadium It's most probably GNOME Flashback.

Comment: Correct it's Gnome Flashback, sorry I'm not very experienced in the Ubuntu configuration/GUI hence the question.

Comment: Any further help on this?

Comment: Is there a setting in the dconf editor I can possibly change for this? I am currently looking through it now but can't seem to find anything.